# Find the volume common to $r^2+z^2=a^2$ and $r=a\sin(\theta)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Sorry to ask another one of these, but I am really struggling with these integrals.

The question asks to find the volume common to $r^2+z^2=a^2$ and $r=a\sin(\theta)$.

I attempted to set up the integral as:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{a\sin(\theta)}r\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta 
$$
Which made sense to me as I am integrating under the manifold $z=\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$ subject to the constraint that $r<a\sin(\theta)$ with $r$ positive as always.

This integral evaluates to 0 though, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You seem to mean the common volume to sphere $\;x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2\;$ and the cylinder $\;x^2+\left(y-\frac a2\right)^2=\frac{a^2}4\;$ , right?

Comment: @Joanpemo I assume? These problems don't provide much exposition. The answer they give is $2(3\pi -4)a^2/9$ if this helps.

Comment: The reason your integral is $0$ is because you've allowed $\theta$ to range from $0$ to $2\pi$. But doing that means your upper limit for $r$ can be negative, and you don't want that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$D=\left\{ (x,y,z)|\,\,{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}}={{a}^{2}}\,,\,\,{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}=ay\, \right\}$$
$$V=\iiint\limits_{D}{dV=}\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{a\sin \theta}{\int_{-\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{r}^{2}}}}^{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{r}^{2}}}}{r\,dz}}}\,dr\,d\theta =\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{a\sin \theta }2r{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{r}^{2}}}}}dr\,d\theta$$
set $u=a^2-r^2$, we have $du=-2r\,dr$ and
$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & r=a\sin \theta \,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,u={{a}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta  \\ 
 & r=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,u={{a}^{2}} \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$
therefore
$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{{{a}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta }^{{{a}^{2}}}{\sqrt{u}}}\,du\,d\theta$$
Now you can easily compute this integral.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. Do you think there is a way to do with with two integrals by any chance? This came from a section on double integration

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it. Please exactly say what do you want.

Comment: I think the book wanted only 2 iterated integrals, whereas here you have three. Not a big deal, but I am curious how they expected me to do this with only 2.

Comment: we want to compute the volume, so we should use 3 iterated integral.

Comment: Not always, right? You can find the volume under some $f(x,y)=z$ subject to some constraints like $a<x<b$ and $g(x)<y<h(x)$ by integrating $\int_a^b\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}zdydx$ which is what I was trying to do

Comment: Especial case $\iint\limits_{A}{\int_{g(r,\theta )}^{h(r,\theta )}r\,{dzdrd\theta }}=\iint\limits_{A}{r(h(r,\theta )-g(r,\theta ))\,\,drd\theta }$